# Mutually singular on complex measure implies equality of total variation?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given a measurable set $(X,{\cal M})$ and a complex measure $\mu$, we say a set $F \in {\cal M}$ is $\mu-$null if for every subset $E \subseteq F$ with $E \in {\cal M}$,$ \ |\mu(E)|=0$

Hence we say two complex measures $\mu,\nu$ on $(X,{\cal M})$ are mutually singular, if there are $E, F \in {\cal M}$ such that $X = E \cup F, E \cap F = \emptyset,$ $E$ is $\mu-$null and $F$ is $\nu-$ null

Show that if $\mu,\nu$ on $(X,{\cal M})$ are mutually singular complex measures, then $|\mu + \nu| = |\mu| +|\nu|$

My trial is to show double inequality, and $|\mu + \nu| \le |\mu| + |\nu|$ is free, but how to show the other direction? Thank you for your help!

Comment: What role is $E$ playing in your definition of $\mu$-null?

Comment: @aduh Sorry, just editted

Comment: Do you know the Hahn decomposition theorem?  What definition of total variation are you using?

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes I know the Hahn decomposition. The total variation is defined as $|\nu|(E) = sup \{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|\nu(E_i)| : (E_i)_{i=1}^{\infty} \subseteq M \  \text{disjoint and} \  \cup E_i = E \}$

Comment: Ok.  So consider the Hahn decompositions for $\mu,\nu$ and try intersecting them appropriately with $E,F$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a prove, working for $\mathbb{R}^N$-valued finite Radon measures, it is surely helpful for your problem.
Let us suppose that $E\in \mathcal{M}$ is the set satisfying $|\mu|(E)=0=|\nu(X\backslash E)|$. 
We show the inequality $|\nu +\mu|\geq|\mu|+|\nu|.$
So, let $A \in \mathcal{M}$ be fixed and $\varepsilon >0$ be given. 
By definition, there are countable partitions of $A$, namely $(A_i)_i$ and $(B_i)_i$, such that $$|\mu|(A)\leq  \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+ \sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}} |\mu(A_i)|$$

and 
$$|\nu|(A)\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}} |\nu(B_i)|.$$
Now, from the choice of $E$, we deduc 
$$\sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}} |\mu(A_i)|=\sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}} |\mu(A_i\backslash E)|=\sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}} |(\mu+\nu)(A_i\backslash E)|$$
and 
$$\sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}} |\nu(B_i)|=\sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}} |\nu(B_i\cap E)|=\sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}} |(\nu+\mu)(B_i\cap E)|.$$

Note that $(A_i \backslash E)_i$ and $(B_i \cap E)$ are countable partitions of $A\backslash E$ and $A\cap E$, respectively.
Therefore

$$(|\mu|+|\nu|)(A) \leq \varepsilon + \sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}} |(\nu+\mu)(B_i\cap E)|+\sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}} |(\mu+\nu)(A_i\backslash E)|\leq \varepsilon + |\mu + \nu|(A\backslash E) + |\mu+\nu |(A \cap E)=|\nu+\mu|(A)+ \varepsilon.$$
Since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we conclude that the desired inequality holds.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\mu\perp\nu$. Let $A,B$ be measurable disjoints sets which partition
$X$, where $A$ is null for $\mu$ and $B$ is null for $\nu$. Let $f$ be the Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mu+\nu$ with respect to some
sigma finite (positive) measure $\lambda$ on $\mathcal M$. Then
$\mu=f\chi_Bd\lambda$, $\nu= f\chi_A d\lambda$ and
$$|\mu|=|f\chi_B|d\lambda,\quad |\nu|= |f\chi_A| d\lambda$$
But now $|f|=|f\chi_B+f\chi_A|=|f\chi_B|+|f\chi_A|$ and so
$$|\mu+\nu|=|f|d\lambda=|f\chi_B|d\lambda+|f\chi_A|d\lambda=|\mu|+|\nu|$$